# quotes , products, services are not getting inserted properly into database

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm

i have created many services, (i.e products in suitecrm) . there are some main services under which some sub services are there. i am mapping all the main services to one product (i.e product category in suitecrm).

now on select of one particular product i need to dispaly all the main services and respactive sub services. upto here i am able to do. it is calculating the total price also.

http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/480856/quotes-products-services-are-not-getting-inserted-properly-into-database

chk this llink . beceause i donthave reputation to post images. plz help me guys as soon as possible